# My design view does not render my XML layout elements

Tags: xml, android-studio-2.2

when I run my Android studio, its Gradle syncs without error and render layout elements well, after I updated it to Android Studio 2.2 it showed me these warnings

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

My after using it for my xml it showed me this error

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Android\Flip\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
```

Error:(685) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Int'l code)
Error:(685) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Int'l code)
C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Android\Flip\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:(12, 17) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').
C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Android\Flip\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\authpopup.xml
Error:(182, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/Code').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Error:(182, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/Code').
>   C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Android\Flip\app\src\main\res\layout\authpopup.xml
>   Error:(12, 17) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').
>   C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Android\Flip\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Error:(182, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/Code').
>   but my authpopup.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Info"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/countrycode"
        android:hint="@string/Code" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/phone_number_slot"
        android:hint="@string/TypeNumber"/></LinearLayout>
```

my strings.xml

```
 <string name="TypeNumber">Type your phonenumber</string>
<string name="Code">Int'l code</string>
```

my value.xml begins to highligt `<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"> //as URI not registered(Settings|Language&Frameworks|SchemasandDTDs)`red

Experts help, am frustrated. None of my XML layout renders
what do you think is the problem?

Comment: Hi guys i resolved it,  its Circular dependencies cannot exist problem

Comment: For those having similar problems this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904281/circular-dependencies-cannot-exist-in-relativelayout-android.  should help